# Stopping accidental deletion of a firebase DB via Firebase Dashboard

Tags: firebase

Does anyone know if its possible to ask for a password or something before deleting certain firebase DB's but not others when you are in the firebase dashboard?

Reason is that we have several firebase instances for development work and then a primary prod one.
We are all over the dev db's all day and often looking at prod as well
We often trash the dev database to clear our system down.

We are highly concerned that one day we are going to accidentally trash the prod database as its just too easy - 2 clicks! The kind of mistake any fool could make.

So, is it possible to configure one of our firebase databases so that you need to enter a password or something similar before you trash that database?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

*Disclaimer: I work at Firebase*

The Firebase Dashboard has an all-or-nothing approach to rights: either you can get in or you can't. So that is unfortunately a "no" to your first question.

That said, there are few things to keep in mind:

1. Firebase makes backups of all databases for disaster recovery purposes at least daily. And "accidentally clicking delete" counts as a disaster.
2. It's probably best to separate developer work (which you do in the dashboard) from application administration. For the latter, you should build a dashboard that prevents the administrator from doing disastrous things. Keep in mind: quite often the same person who is the developer is the application administrator. But I find that even in those cases, it is best to protect the users of my applications from the developer-version of me.