# Allow Firebase collaborators access to specific nodes

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I have an app that uses Firebase and I have a few people that need to be able to update data in the Firebase Dashboard. Luckily, Firebase added the feature to add collaborators. But the problem is, I don't want these collaborators to have access to every node of the JSON. Is there a way that I can assign collaborators specific access to certain nodes of the data structure or no?

Any feedback would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collaborators on the Firebase project/app have access to all data. There is no way to limit that.

It sounds like you are looking to add application administrator. For this you'll have to develop your own application dashboard, where you add such functionality. These application administrators are then just regular users of your app and you can use [Firebase security rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/) to determine what data they have access to.

Very similar: [Stopping accidental deletion of a firebase DB via Firebase Dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30871391/stopping-accidental-deletion-of-a-firebase-db-via-firebase-dashboard)